# Finding time complexity of a specific python algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity

Hi I need to understand what is the time complexity of the following algorithm.

```
def complex(n):
    l=[]
    i=1
    while i<n:
        l=list(range(i))
        i*=2
```

I've got to the point where I realized it runs int(log(n,2)) times over the loop but I'm having hard time incorporating the range(i) into the final expression.
Any help appreciated thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Do you have any guesses or thoughts?  Right now, this just seems to be a *please do my homework* type post.

Comment: I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to solve this. I'm thinking it's around log(n) but I just can get from there to the solution.

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to "declare variables at the top" in Python, like that `l=[]` at the top of your function.

Comment: Well I tried and I'm stuck. I can't get to a precise expression. I'm thinking it's around log(n) but can't get things from there. If you could help that would be nice if not, thanks anyway.

Comment: A guess doesn't count for much. Can you work out how many times it goes through the loop? (You can even test that one by adding a counter into your code and running it with different values, if you can't be sure you've figured it out right.) And how much work it does each time through the loop? (That ones a bit harder to test, but `timeit` and a wide range of very large values should help.)  Once you have those, it's just a matter of combining them. If you get stuck at one of those points, you'll have a more specific question.

Comment: @abarnert yes I know, I just wanted to simplify things.

Comment: @abanert I've done that already I'm stuck at developing an expression that would define the number of iterations done each time.

Comment: I'm not sure which comment you're responding to, but if it's my first one, adding unnecessary bits of code that have no effect doesn't simplify things, and if it's your second one, not explaining the work you've already done and where you're stuck so we can help you get unstuck doesn't simplify things either.

Comment: And when you say "I've done that already", _what_ have you done already? What information have you gathered? How? What about it makes you think there's a log(n) involved here?

Comment: because it runs int(log(n,2)) iterations my problem is with the range(i)

Comment: OK, that's a real question. If you'd just asked that in the first place—or in the second place, after @MikeChristensen asked where you were stuck—that would have been helpful. Please edit the question to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You've already worked out that it runs `int(log(n, 2))` iterations. (You can test that very easily by just adding a counter into the loop, and calling it with, e.g., 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc., and seeing that the counter goes up 1 every time `n` doubles.)

Now you want to know how long the inside of the loop takes. Here, you'd need to know the time complexity of the `range` and `list` functions. I can give you the answers to those, and in fact you might be able to guess them, but you can't really *prove* that unless you start reading the source code to CPython. So, let's test it with some simple timing:

```
import timeit
for i in range(20):
    n = 1 << i
    t = timeit.timeit(lambda: list(range(n))
    print('{} takes {}'.format(n, t))
```

If you run this, you'll see that, once you get beyond around 32, doubling `n` seems to double the time it takes. So, that means `list(range(n))` is O(n), right?

Let's verify whether that makes sense. I don't know whether you're using Python 2.x or 3.x, so I'll work it out both ways.

In 2.x: `range(n)` has to calculate `n` integers, and build a list `n` values long. That seems like it ought to be O(n).

In 3.x: `range(n)` just returns an object that remembers the number `n`. That ought to be O(1). But then we call `list` on that `range`, which has to iterate the whole range, calculating all `n` integers, and building a list `n` values long. So it's still O(n).

Put that back into your loop, and you have O(log n) times through the loop, each one O(i) complexity. So, the total time is O(1) + O(2) + O(4) + O(…) + O(n/4) + O(n/2) + O(n), with log(n) steps in the summation. In other words, it's the sum of a [geometric sequence](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html). And now you can solve the problem. (Or, if not, you're stuck on a new part, which someone can answer for your very simply if you can't figure it out yourself.)

---

You worked out that the sum is `-(1-2**log(n,2))`. That's not quite right, because you wanted a closed range, not a half-open range, so it should be `-(1-2**log(n+1,2))`. But that's probably my fault for not explaining it clearly, and it doesn't matter too much, so  let's go with your version first.

`2**log(n, 2)` is obviously `n`. (If you don't understand exponentiation and logarithms well enough to understand why, you should find a tutorial on the math, but meanwhile you can test it with a variety of different values of `n` to convince yourself.)

Meanwhile, `-(1-x)` for any `x` is just `x-1`.

So, the sum is just `n-1`.

If you go back and use the correct `log(n+1, 2)` instead of `log(n, 2)`, you'll get `2n-1`.

So, is that correct? Let's test with some actual numbers.

If `n = 16`, you get `1+2+4+8+16 = 31 = 2n-1`. If `n = 1024`, you get `1+2+4+…+256+512+1024 = 2047 = 2n-1`. Any power-of-2 you throw at it, you get exactly the right answer. For a non-power-of-2, like 1000, you get `1+2+4+…+256+512+1000 = 2023`, which is not exactly `2n-1`, but it's always within a factor of 2. (In fact, it's `n + 2**(ceil(log(n, 2)) - 1`, or `n + m - 1` where `m` is the `n` rounded up to a power of 2.)

Anyway, `n-1`, `2n-1`, `n + 2**(ceil(log(n, 2)) - 1`… those are all `O(n)`.

And you can go back and test this by timing the whole function with different values of `n` and see that, beyond very small numbers, when you double `n` it takes about twice as long.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer but I'm still rather confused about that last paragraph. what is the formal way to represent such a summation?

Comment: @user2980240: Well, it's clearly a [geometric sequence](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html), right? Each `x[i]` is `a * r**i`, and `a` is some constant we don't care about and `r` is `2`, where `i` ranges from 0 to `log(n, 2)`. The summation formula is given further down the page I just linked. If you can't work it out from there, try evaluating that for various different numbers (it's easiest with powers of 2) and finding the pattern.

Comment: nope still stuck |= I got to (-(1-2**log(n,2))) which doesn't describe it very well...

Comment: Sure it does. Let me edit the answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This one is trickier than it looks, because `list(range(i))` is based on i, which grows geometrically. There is a simple way to look at the problem, however. How many elements are created, in total, relative to n? You can simplify the problem by assuming convenient values of n, i.e., powers of two.

If you're still stuck, start small and go up. If n = 1, how many elements are created in total? Then see what answer you get for n = 2, n = 4, n = 8, and so on. The pattern should become obvious fairly quickly.